# Link Error 1120 and 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl, header, linker-errors

I was developing a program with some headers. One of them is `IO.h` and there is a `Source.cpp`which use this header.
I want to use STL to make developing my project easier but I received error!
All I have in `Source.cpp` is:

```
vector<string>* AttribDic = NULL;
```

up to here there is no problem but as I want to use the following function is `IO.h` I get the mentioned errors at the the top:

```
void getAttrib(vector<string>* dictionary,int attribNum);
void getInformation(vector<string>* dictionary,int attribNum, Record * r);
```

I read the Microsoft MSDN and other stack pages about this error. but I found nothig helpful up to here.

Comment: Those are not the error messages... Those are just function declarations. Please give the full error messages.

Comment: No The mentioned error..

Comment: Linking errors have nothing to do with headers, they usually indicate absence of needed library. To get some help, post *full* text of error messages.

Comment: LNK1120 one unresolved externals

Comment: LNK2019 :...(same as the previous) symbol "void __cdecl getRecords(void)" (?getRecords@@YAXXZ....